# Spring Microservice Eureka Client Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/},

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, netflix-eureka

I have one eureka Server that has multiple clients, I have deployed the micro services to to a docker container, whenever I do `docker compose pull`, and do `docker compose up -d`,  Eureka server starts on `http://localhost:8761/eureka/` instead of `'http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/`. What am I doing wrong in setting the eureka to use the docker config instead of the local

This is my Eureka-Server Config

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server
  zipkin:
    base-url: http://zipkin:9411

server:
  ports:
    - "8761:8761"
eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: false
    register-with-eureka: false
```

The APiGW Docker config

```
server:
  port: 8083

spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  zipkin:
    base-url: http://zipkin:9411
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: customer
          uri: lb://CUSTOMER
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/v1/customers/**

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
```

My Docker Compose file

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-db
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ornaccode
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin
    container_name: zipkin
    ports:
      - "9411:9411"
    networks:
      - spring
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.9.11-management-alpine
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    networks:
      - spring
  eureka-server:
    image: remymumoh/eureka-server:latest
    container_name: eureka-server
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
  apigw:
    image: remymumoh/apigw:latest
    container_name: apigw
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - eureka-server
  customer:
    image: remymumoh/customer:latest
    container_name: customer
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - eureka-server
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
  fraud:
    image: remymumoh/fraud:latest
    container_name: fraud
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - eureka-server
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
  notification:
    image: remymumoh/notification:latest
    container_name: notification
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - spring
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
      - eureka-server
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
  spring:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

My Error log

```
Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/}, exception=I/O error on GET request for "http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/apps/": Connect to eureka-server:8761 [eureka-server/172.29.0.4] failed: Connection refused; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to eureka-server:8761 [eureka-server/172.29.0.4] failed: Connection refused stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/apps/": Connect to eureka-server:8761 [eureka-server/172.29.0.4] failed: Connection refused; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to eureka-server:8761 [eureka-server/172.29.0.4] failed: Connection refused
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:145)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:135)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:121)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:80)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1101)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1014)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:441)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:283)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:279)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:66)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:295)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:374)
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:376)
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:179)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:371)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:127)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:115)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:485)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1991a9f7.getEurekaClient(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:54)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:765)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:445)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
        at com.ornac.apigw.ApiGWApplication.main(ApiGWApplication.java:11)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to eureka-server:8761 [eureka-server/172.29.0.4] failed: Connection refused
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776)
        ... 68 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
        at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
```

When I do `http://localhost:8761/eureka/` on the browser,  I can reach the eureka-server but when I use the URL for docker `http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/` I am not able. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add hostname like:

```
  eureka-server:
    image: remymumoh/eureka-server:latest
    container_name: eureka-server
    hostname: eureka-server
```